# How to get POST data of a navigator from another page

Tags: javascript, php, navigation

I'm currently working on a payment plug-in for wordpress/woocommerce and i have an issue  with a method  of payment which require a redirection that would break the flow payment tunnel asked by the client. So I was thinking about using a Paypal like  method with 2 page  communicating  with one another but I have no idea how to start.

At this point the solution would be perfect but I have no starting point  nor idea about how to proceed. 
I use PHP and JS Fetch Api but I proceed in the redirection which break the  flow as mentioned.

```
fetch("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", {
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
}).then(function (response) {
    //get json
    return response.json(); //parse la reponse en JSON
}).then(function (data) {
    // get data response
    if (select_method() === "card") {
        // if is card -> triger redirection
        var url = new URL(data.redirect.url);
        params = data.redirect.data;
        url.searchParams.append('PaReq', params.PaReq);
        url.searchParams.append('TermUrl', params.TermUrl);
        url.searchParams.append('MD', params.MD);
        document.cookie = "paymentData =" + JSON.stringify(data.paymentData);
        document.cookie = "paiementData =" + (data.paymentData);
        document.getElementById('hidenForm').action = url.href;
        document.getElementById("hidenForm").submit();//TRIGGER DU FORM
    }
})
```

This is what I use to proceed right now at the end I just trigger a hidden form.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on now? Question seems a bit broad as it stands. Are you stuck on sending the data with Xhr/AJAX to another page? Or are you looking for HTTP functions server side? Like cURL? You will find many examples of both those if you search. Suggest trying and asking something specific here when you get stuck (always share the code).

Comment: The problems here is that I have to trigger a check-out without having a redirect. Both the payments and the check-out works. But it seems that the redirection due to the 3Dsecure challenge break the flow.